# Laravel: Set name of validation rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have created a Rule object using `php artisan make:rule HasColumn`. It checks if the given column exists in the table given in parameter.

Here is the code:

```
class HasColumn implements Rule {
    protected $table;

    public function __construct($table) {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value) {
        return Schema::hasColumn($this->table,$value);
    }

    public function message() {
        return 'The :attribute must be a valid column name.';
    }
}
```

How can I set a name to this validation rule, so that I can simply do:

```
$req->validate(['column' => 'has_column,users']);
```

instead of:

```
$req->validate(['column' => new HasColumn('users'));
```

Thank you for your help.